# How to replace 'strange' signs?

Tags: vim, replace, vi

When I open a file using vi I see the following line:

```
00:00:15:Co<9c> Ty!
```

What is hidden under `<9c>` and how can I make a global replacement for all occurrences of this strange sign? File is encoded with UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<9c>` is the single character with the value `0x9c` = decimal 156; in UTF-8, this is `U+009C String Terminator`. You can replace it via one of the following alternatives:

- Yank the character (`yl`) and insert it in a `:substitute` command via `:help c_CTRL-R`: `:%s/<C-r>"//g`
- Enter the character via its hex value in the `:substitute` command: `:%s/<C-v>x9c//g`; cp. `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`.
- Enter the character via the special `\%x9c` regular expression atom in the `:substitute` command: `:%s/\%x9c//g`; cp. `:help /\%x`.

Comment: Actually replacement that worked for me was: `:%s/\%uYYYY/substitute/g`

Comment: Yes, that's another alternative; added it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains the byte 0x9c, as previously mentioned in [Ingo Karkat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30013586/4896941). When a text file contains bytes in the range 0x80–0x9f, it oftentimes indicates that the file is in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding (or a different [Windows code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) for non–Western-European locales).

To view the file as a Windows-1252–encoded file in Vim, enter `:e ++encoding=windows-1252`. The text in the question then appears as

```
00:00:15:Coœ Ty!
```

I can't tell you if that is the correct character, though. If instead the intended encoding is Windows-1250, for Central European languages, the command `:e ++encoding=windows-1250` will make the text appear as

```
00:00:15:Coś Ty!
```